# Problem with package installation of pstricks

Tags: packages, pstricks, texstudio, miktex2.9

[image]

I installed miktek and texstudio from internet when started using package pstriks it firstly asked to install from internet i have permission but again after running same dialogue box opened it happened 3-4 times than after viewing answer on internet i installed package of pstricks-add and pdftrick,etc package in miktek because for Pstricks it was showing installed by admin and neither was able to install or uninstall Pstricks than tried upgrading miktek but none was available than updated database ,etc but still the problem continue 
The commands were.

```
\documentclass {article}
 \usepackage{Pstricks} 
\usepackage{pspicture} 
\begin{document} 
\maketitle
 \begin {pspicture}(5,5)
 \psline(1,1)(-5,1)(1,4)(2,1)
 \end {pspicture} 
\end {document}
```

And error was

```
undefined control sequence \psline (
```

and so so –

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Please post a minimal, but complete code that reproduces your problem.

Comment: show your code!

Comment: I installed miktek and texstudio from internet when started using package pstriks it firstly asked to install from internet i have permission but again after running same dialogue box opened it happened 3-4 times than after viewing answer on internet i installed package of pstricks-add and pdftrick,etc package in miktek because for Pstricks it was showing installed by admin and neither was able to install or uninstall Pstricks than tried upgrading miktek but none was available than updated database ,etc but still the problem continue

Comment: The commands were.      \document class {article} \usepackage{Pstricks} \usepackage{pspicture} \begin{document} \maketitle \begin {pspicture}(5,5) \psline(1,1)(-5,1)(1,4)(2,1) \end {pspicture} \end {document}

Comment: And error was undefined control sequence \psline ( and so so

Comment: `\usepackage{pstricks}`  lowercase letters

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in comments ...